# Laravel not returning a specific view and stays on white page after a class is constructed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\MovieDataController::class, 'init']); // <-- after this page breaks down
```

NivueDataController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\movieData;


class MovieDataController extends Controller
{
    public function init(){
        MovieDataController::console_log("init called");
        MovieDataController::getPopular();
        MovieDataController::index();
    }

    ///////////////////////////FOR DBG PURPOSES ONLY////////////////////////////////////////
        function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) {
            $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) . 
        ');';
            if ($with_script_tags) {
                $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
            }
            echo $js_code;
        }
    ///////////////////////////FOR DBG PURPOSES ONLY////////////////////////////////////////
    public function index()
    {
        MovieDataController::console_log("returning index view");
        return view('index');
    }
    protected function create(string $data)
    {
        return movieData::create([
            'movie_id' => $data, 
        ]);
    }

    function getPopular(){
        $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => 
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "X-RapidAPI-Host:",
                "X-RapidAPI-Key: "
            ],
        ]);

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        $response = str_replace('/title/', '', $response);
        $response = str_replace('/', '', $response);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } 
        else {
            $arrayt = [];
            foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
            array_push($arrayt, $response[$key]);
        }
        foreach ($arrayt as $key => $value) {
            MovieDataController::create($arrayt[$key]);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this issue for couple hours now and I haven't been able to find out why is MovieDataController breaking my site apart.

I've tried debug logging to see if something goes into loop/ or freezes it, but I haven't been able to determine whats the issue.

EDIT: by breaking my site I mean my view is not there anymore, its just a blank page.

Comment: side note: you have 3 routes defined all with the same path and HTTP method; only one of them will actually be registered ... second thing why are you calling all these methods statically when you are inside the class? and you are not **returning** anything from your route action so why would you expect anything other than a blank response?

Answer (score 0):

## Debugging

Right off the bat, you're only declaring one route at `/` — they can't all have the same URI.

What do the logs tell you? (`/storage/logs/laravel.*`) Post them?

#### Route Visibility

Laravel routes must be **PUBLIC** not protected or private.... you're also calling it statically down in the `foreach` and the function is not declared as static. This might not be your issue, but Laravel Controllers use specific verbs (eg `create`) so you should probably rename the `create()` function to avoid issues there — in general, just call the `Model::create()` directly vs using a helper-function. If there's a common task you need to do upon creation look into [Eloquent Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events), [DTOs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v2/introduction), or even a broken out Service — it's generally best practice to NOT have misc functions on Controllers. In MVC they should be super simple and only manage high-level-logic/request/response (validation is even deferred to Requests).

### Route Declerations:

You are declaring three different routes to `GET /`. Try this:

```php
# PHP 8+

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MovieDataController;

// Avoid inline functions and prefer controllers — limits caching/performance
Route::get('/', fn () => view('index'))->name('index');

Route::prefix('home')->name('home.)->group(function () {
  Route::get('index', HomeController::class . '@index')->name('index');
});

Route::prefix('movie-data')->name('movie-data.)->group(function () {
  Route::get('init', MovieDataController::class . '@init')->name('init');
});

/* Run `php artisan route:list` to see the routes */
```

### Controller

### Use of CURL

#### Use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http`

Why are you using `curl_init()`? It's 2022? Use Laravel's `HTTP` Facade ((docs)[https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client]). It's so much better and makes testing a lot easier.

There's a very real chance that an exception is being thrown that you are either missing or would be apparent or handled by the `HTTP` Facade.

#### JSON Parsing

It's possible that parsing the JSON is failing and hanging. Look into handling errors & double-check your PHP Version (update if possible!). You could even look into using a DTO library to handle parsing the response ([Spatie Laravel-Data](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v2/introduction))

#### Close CURL connection ASAP

If you insist on using `curl`, close the connection ASAP (before `str_replace()`)

### Lint that file

Your formatting might be off and/or you might have a missing closing bracket—though, that would probably produce a different error (Logs?). Try running `php -l /path/to/controller.php`.

## Extra Credit (PR Review Learning Comments)

#### Function Naming

Laravel prefers CamelCase functions vs snake_cases. Extend this to everything but raw `Model->attribute_name`.

eg `MovieDataController::console_log() -> MovieDataController::consoleLog()`
*It's also weird to see `console_log` in the backend given it's a JavaScript function ... Laravel/PHP use `dump/var_dump` — try to follow existing standards as much as possible.

Comment: `curl_init()` is still ok in 2022 too. HTTP facade is not an equal replacement for curl in all cases. Secondly, even if the route is correct, he will still get a blank response because he isn't returning anything.

Comment: @itachi — I'm unaware of any use cases where the Laravel HTTP Facade cannot deprecate "raw curl" calls? As to the blank response, the OP specifies that they are returning a `view()` from the endpoint — assumed to be the root `/` URI — which won't be empty unless the view is empty (hence the suggestion to check and/or post the laravel logs) ... maybe I'm misunderstanding your point?